# MAX function : Display name of sheet where the answer is

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have several sheets in my Excel file, all named according to a day of the month (So from 1 to 31). I also have another sheet named "totals". In this sheet I have a MAX function that returns the highest number in cell Q31 from ALL sheets. In short, I ask to Excel: What is the highest number among the 31 "Q31" cells. Excel gives me the answer, for example, 54.

I would rather have Excel give me the name of the sheet where it finds the answer.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the max formula you are using?

Comment: @ScottCraner I am using =MAX('1:31'!Q34) but it's not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **A1** through **A31** enter:

```
=INDIRECT(ROW() & "!Q31")
```

then in **B1** enter:

```
=MATCH(MAX(A:A),A:A,0)
```

*(assumes the sheets are "named" 1,2,3,... and the worksheet name corresponds to the row number in column **A**)*